# How do I get wind in km/h in PyOWM?

Tags: python, openweathermap

I made a program that retrieves the current weather in users city using PyOWM.

I am having trouble understanding how to display wind using km/h in PyOWM.

I tried making conversions but when I checked the current weather on Google, it was always wrong.

Does the weather update every hour?
The code in question:

```
print("Wind:",round((w.wind().get("speed",0)),2),"km/h")
```

w being observation.weather, observation being mgr.weather_at_place(asd), asd being location of user input

Full Code:

```
from pyowm import OWM

country = input("Enter your country code: ")
city = input("Enter your city name: ")
owm = OWM("xxxxxxxxx")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
asd = city + ", " + country
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(asd)
w = observation.weather
w.wind()
print("Wind:", round((w.wind().get("speed", 0)), 2), "km/h")
```

Comment: It would be easier to follow your question if you included a complete, minimum working example. Add the actual code that creates `w`, and show your actual output.

Comment: In the question, please, not in the comments. I'd like to be able to just cut and paste.

Comment: you said you "compared it to google"...did you instead compare it to the data on openweathermap.org ... keep in mind wind speeds can fluctuate and google might be a getting from a different source/station than openweathermap ...i know the us national weather service does an hourly update...i assume most underlying sources work similarly with some update interval

Comment: I googled "current wint in *city*" and it came up with very different results than my program

Comment: Also, I'm not from US, I am from Croatia so idk if we do hourly updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives the windspeed in m/s. You need to convert it to km/h by multiplying the returned value by 3.6.

Comment: Yep, that was it!